# Laravel working with collection filter and map

Tags: php, laravel, filter

I have a method where I can return the upcoming payment date. In the below example, `getNextDate()` will return a Carbon date, like so:

```
Carbon @1549788696 {#1119 ▼
  date: 2019-02-10 08:51:36.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

I basically have a bunch of `subscriptions` in the database, and I want to show only `one` result in my view, of the next upcoming payment date.

Example, let's say I have three subscriptions:

```
Subscription 1, getNextDate() will return: 2019-02-18
Subscription 2, getNextDate() will return: 2019-02-10
Subscription 3, getNextDate() will return: 2019-02-25
```

Since `Subscription 2` is the next upcoming that needs to be paid, I want to show only that one, in a widget in my view. How would I go about it? Using filter or map for example, like below?

```
$subscriptions = auth()->user()->subscriptions()->get();

$filtered = $subscriptions->filter(function ($subscription) {
    return $subscription->getNextDate();
});

dd($filtered);
```

This will just return all of them. But is there a way I can filter it so I get one result only, for the next closest `getNextDate()`? Or should I do this way differently? Any suggestions will do.

PS. The `getNextDate()` simply grabs the `start_date` for a subscription, then calculates the difference in months from `Carbon::now()` and checks how many payments have been made until now, and then returns the next upcoming payment date. So nothing fancy going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `filter()` here. I think the following should work.

```
$subscriptions = auth()->user()->subscriptions()->get();

$next = $subscriptions->sortBy(function ($subscription) {
    return $subscription->getNextDate()->timestamp;
})->first();
```

You need to sort your collection by ascending order of the next date and get the first item.

Comment: Do you even need the collection sort? This should be doable on the query by adding an orderByRaw and using first() to only get 1. You could even use the orderByRaw to pass in a Carbon calculation.